# nvidia driver not working after system update

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, dkms

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. My graphic card is Nvidia GTX 650. It perfectly worked with the `nvidia-driver-435` recommended by `ubuntu-drivers devices`.

After performing system update (with Ubuntu GUI update manager) and rebooting, the nvidia driver is no more used and screen resolution is maybe 640x480. I do not remember exactly which packages have been upgraded.

I have:

```
$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Moreover, `lspci` doesn't show the nvidia proprietary drivers I installed:

```
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

I tried reinstalling them with `sudo apt purge nvidia-driver-435` and then `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-435`; I also ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-driver-435`. Nothing changed. I have `dkms` installed. My current kernel is`4.15.0-76-generic` `x86_64`.

I found several similar questions, but they are too old (2012) or they suggest to [manually install drivers](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-i-fixed-my-display-resolution-by-installing-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux-489563052f6c), which I would like to avoid.

How to make `nvidia-driver-435` working again on my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-driver-435
$ sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-dkms-435
```

If a different driver number is used, replace `435` with it. I don't know if the first step is strictly necessary, but I performed it anyway.